# Spatial Histogram of binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

Is there a good way(automated) to plot a spatial histogram on binary images(the histogram x-axis should be the width of image, y-axis should be the intensity of images at col position),  using Opencv and C++?

I could only think of summing up the image intensity (only 1 or 0) in this case along the columns of image.. but to display them is still not quite clear to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think I am getting close to the answer.

First I have divided out the image into bins of certain width and equal length. This is neccessary as bins of width size equal to 1 pixel would not work too well. Reason being

- The algorithm would work too slowly as it needs to collect n bins with n being the width size
- for a real life application, the spatial image or the intensity pattern might be diffuse and would probably give a result of having equal bin strength

Next I would transverse across the image width or bin width to assign the image intensity with certain threshold to the bin. A histogram is then build to represent the rough shape of the pattern

And if I needed a picture that shows the histogram, I would

1. Create a Mat of size ( max_bin_weights, number of bin)
2. Then create std::vector.  Each Point coordinate (0.5 * nth bin, weight of nth bin)
3. Plot out the histogram by iterating through the std::vector. Connecting the previous point to the current point using cv::line